# Overpaid in cash at out of state hospital, they wont pay back

Tags: payment, currency

In Nevada, I needed some care at a hospital. After treatment, they told me I owed $1600 so I trusted them and paid in cash. Turns out I actually only owed about $1100, so they owe me $500. I live in Illinois.

I've called 5 times now, and every time its the same story: we agree we owe you money, the last person in charge of putting the request in messed up and didnt submit it properly, we're putting it through now, youll get a check in 2 weeks.

This has gone on for 6 months. What is my best course of action here to recover the $500?

Comment: Name of hospital? Public or private?

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with recalcitrant agencies, governments, businesses or otherwise who move very slowly or refuse to deal with genuine consumer issues - like refunds they have agreed to - one thing to do is *carefully* up the ante. You need to get them to take you seriously, and one way is to potentially get some third party help.

Call the hospital billing department and say if they don't resolve this issue - which they admit exists - you're going to file a complaint with a consumer advocate, like [Nevada Consumer Affairs .gov](http://consumeraffairs.nv.gov/) and/or get legal help from a non-profit or pro-bono legal aid firm, like [Pro Bono Legal Services - State Bar of Nevada](https://www.nvbar.org/lawyerreferral/pro-bono-for-the-public/).

I say *carefully* because you don't want to say *I'm going to sue!* or get angry and threaten anything. Just tell them you're looking at all your options. And that may resolve the matter right there; they don't want to deal with the extra work of a complaint from the state government or a letter from an attorney, and you may have your refund quickly.

If it doesn't, look at filing a complaint with the online form at Nevada Consumer Affairs, or call a free or pro bono legal clinic and see about getting help. Sometimes a formal complaint or a letter from a lawyer will quickly resolve things.

Comment: Yes, technically it’s illegal to threaten legal action you have no intention of taking.